# What are the steps needed to create a ligature?

Tags: ligatures

If I want to make my own ligature, even if it's strange, for example for "rb" with a curl similar to those in "ct" or "st", or even mor strange such as a ligature for "or", using instead of the "o" the oval of the "g" in order to add a curl all the way to end on top of the "r"; or a triple ligature for "orb",... where do I start?

Comment: you need a font editing program, and some artistic skill, but it's off topic for this site as TeX itself has no control over this, the ligatures have to be drawn and specified in the font.

Comment: Check `fontforge`.